# Textarea Position Absolute Pushes Parent div

Tags: html, css

Hello all CSS newbie here,

I have a special case, where I want to position a text area on the edge of a div. I want the text area to be cropped even when a user types into the text area. I'm deeply confused on why does the textarea grows and pushes the position of the parent div even though I have set the parent div overflow to hidden ? Any ideas so that the textarea position stays as is (cropped)?

My code is as below:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='box'>
    <textarea class="text"/>
  </div
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
}

.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  right:-250px;
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  resize:none;
}
```

Here is the link to my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/andreSatria/pen/dyMxqxX)

Thank you and deeply appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
}

.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.text {
  max-width:300px;
  height:50px;
  right: 0;
  background:yellow;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  resize:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='box'>
    <textarea class="text"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your html code is not correct. And I used max-width for textarea.

Comment: Hi Ishita Ray, thank you for your comment and suggestion. However, what I did is on purpose as I am planning for the user to be able to move the textarea around... My problem roots from a case where the user moves the textarea on the edge hence overflows from the parent. PS. I also have tried limiting the width of the textarea relative to the parent edge.... however UX wise is not very satisfiable as the texarea would grow downwards (as I want the textarea to maintain its width)

Comment: You have mentioned textarea 300px width